# HTML / JS - Get selected element class and/or ID

Tags: javascript, html, web, dom

I am aware of how to use `document.getSelection()` to get the string of whatever text the user highlights.

However, how do I access the `class` and/or `id` of the element from `getSelection()`?

Any thoughts?

Comment: `.getSelection` returns an object with a lot of properties. You might want to take a look at the `focusNode` property and the `parentNode` property inside of `focusNode`. These point to regular `HTMLElement`s from which you can easily select the class/id.

Answer (score 2):

In the object which `getSelection()` returns you can find the `focusNode`. `focusNode` includes the `parentNode`. Inside that you can find the class and id which you are looking for.

```js
function getSelectionId(){
    return getSelection().focusNode.parentNode.id
}
```

```html
<p id=foo>Select text from this paragraph and then click the button and it should print "foo" which is the id of the paragraph.</p>

<button onclick=console.log(getSelectionId())>Log selection id</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

I got your problem, Basically, the getSelection() method returns a Selection object representing the range of text selected by the user or the current position of the caret, You can get the class and id from the getSelection(); But, there are few ways to get class and id value from your HTML page to Javascript.

- First one, { For Class } `const anything = document.getElementByClassName("Anything")`;
- Second one, { For ID } `const anything = document.getElementById("Anything")`;
- Third one, For id and class... It will work on both - `const selector = document.querySelector(".class #id")`;
- A quick javascript snippet
- `const cookies = document.getElementById("id-container") cookies.classList.toggle("active")`

Follow, this strategy for selecting classNames and id instead of getSelection();

Comment: _"You cant' get the class and id from the getSelection()"_ That's wrong. You can.

Comment: Where did i done a mistake ? Have, you any opinion about it. to fix it ?

Comment: The sentence is wrong. You wrote, you can't get the class name or ID from the selection, but you can. The selection contains a reference to the node. You can get the ID and class names of the node and of its parent nodes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @AdisonMasih Thanks for your help... I'll try to write good answers which is understandable for more in community.

Comment: Your answer still doesn't answer the question. The question is how get the ID and class name of an element. You are showing how to get an element by ID or class name. That's the opposite.